# kendo Chart labels- clickable?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

In the example: http://jsbin.com/AreqameT/1/edit   Can the labels below the bar chart made clickable in kendo charts?
The text "Sales and Contracting" and other labels should be made clickable. Can this be done?

JS code:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  legend: {
    position: "bottom"
  },
  seriesDefaults: {

        labels:{
            visible:true,
            template: '#=kendo.format("{0:0}", value)#'
        }

  },
  series: [
    {   
      type: "verticalBullet",
      currentField: "score",
      targetField: "average",
      labels: {
        visible: true,
        template: '#alert(1)#"'
      },
      target: {
        color: "transparent",
        border: {
          width: 2,
          dashType: "dot",
          color: "#444"
        },
        line: {
          width: 0
        }
      },
      data: [
        {
          score: 93.7,
          average: 65.2                              
        }, {
          score: 80.2,
          average: 22.2
        }, {
          score: 60.8,
          average: 35.2
        }, {

          score: 82.1,
          average: 45.2                                
        }, {
          score: 74.2,
          average: 55.2
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  categoryAxis: {
    labels: { rotation: -45 },
    categories: ["Sales & Contracting", "Implementation & Training", "Functionality & Upgrades", "Service & Support", "General"],
    line: {
      visible: false
    },
    color: "#444", 
    axisCrossingValue: [0, 0, 100, 100]
  },
  tooltip: {
    visible: false
  }
}).data("kendoChart");
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using a newer version of Kendo (your jsBin uses a 2013 version... update to 2014.2) you can use `categoryAxis.labels.template` to add a link to your labels.

```
  categoryAxis: {
    labels: {
      rotation: -45,
      template: '<a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">#: value #</a>'
    },
```

(note the addition of `xlink:` in the tag)

To better explain, the labels are actually part of an SVG image, not plain HTML. However, SVG supports links: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#Links

For some reason the older 2013 version of Kendo seem to remove the link from the template though. I tried it with 2014.2.716 and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your Jsbin eg not working. Attach a event axisLabelClick or legendItemClick

```
axisLabelClick: function(e) {
    console.log(e.axis.type, e.value);
  }

legendItemClick: function(e) {
    console.log(e.axis.type, e.value);
  }
```

this might work